# Marketo integrate to custom app

Tags: integration, marketo

I want to integrate marketo with my web app. In such way that the marketo leads or data automatically sync to app at regular interval.
My web application is in php.
I am new to marketo, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way this is done is by connecting to Marketo Via the Marketo REST or SOAP API, documentation to get you started can be found here:

http://developers.marketo.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

There are several integration platforms available today that let you connect various web apps and automate tasks through a simple interface. These cloud integration platforms use API of the web applications in the backend. All you need to do is connect the apps together and configure the settings. You can connect your own app or on-prem system to web services like Marketo, Salesforce, etc.

Here's a short blog post that shows how apps can be integrated.

https://www.built.io/blog/favorite-services-coupled-together

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to sync data back and forth a webhook might do it for you. That is what I currently use to sync data from Marketo to a PHP app and back to Marketo. Lots of *addons* to Marketo actually work this way.

Webhooks are also a lot easier/quicker to set up on the Marketo end and then on the PHP side you basically just have to handle the POST.

Marketo Webhook Docs: http://developers.marketo.com/webhooks/